# How to optimize join which causes very slow performace

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

This query runs more than 12 seconds, even though all tables are relatively small - about 2 thousands rows.

```
SELECT attr_73206_ AS attr_73270_ 
 FROM object_73130_ f1 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT id_field, attr_73206_ FROM (
     SELECT m.id_field, t0.attr_73102_ AS attr_73206_ FROM object_73200_ o
     INNER JOIN master_slave m ON (m.id_object = 73130 OR m.id_object = 73290) AND (m.id_master = 73200 OR m.id_master = 73354) AND m.id_slave_field = o.id 
     INNER JOIN object_73101_ t0 ON t0.id = o.attr_73206_ 
     ORDER BY o.id_order 
   ) AS o GROUP BY o.id_field 
 ) AS o ON f1.id = o.id_field
```

Both tables have fields `id` as primary keys. Besides, `id_field`, `id_order`,`attr_73206_` and all fields in `master_slave` are indexed. As for the logic of this query, on the whole it's of master-detail kind. Table `object_73130_` is a master-table, table `object_73200_` is a detail-table. They are linked by a `master_slave` table. `object_73101_` is an ad-hoc table used to get a real value for the field `attr_73206_` by its id. For each row in the master table the query returns a field from the very first row of its detail table. Firstly, the query had another look, but here at stackoverflow I was advised to use this more optimized structure (instead of a subquery which was used previously, and, by the way, the query started to run much faster). I observe that the subquery in the first `JOIN` block runs very fast but returns a number of rows comparable to the number of rows in the main master-table. In any way, I do not know how to optimize it. I just wonder why a simple fast-running join causes so much trouble. Oh, the main observation is that if I remove an ad-hoc `object_73101_` from the query to return just an id, but not a real value, then the query runs as quick as a flash. So, all attention should be focused on this part of the query

```
INNER JOIN object_73101_ t0 ON t0.id = o.attr_73206_
```

Why does it slow down the whole query so terribly?

**EDIT**

In this way it runs super-fast

```
SELECT t0.attr_73102_ AS attr_73270_ 
FROM object_73130_ f1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73206_ FROM (
    SELECT m.id_field, attr_73206_ FROM object_73200_ o
    INNER JOIN master_slave m ON (m.id_object = 73130 OR m.id_object = 73290)  AND (m.id_master = 73200 OR m.id_master = 73354) AND m.id_slave_field = o.id 
    ORDER BY o.id_order 
) AS o GROUP BY o.id_field 
) AS o ON f1.id = o.id_field
LEFT JOIN object_73101_ t0 ON t0.id = o.attr_73206_
```

So, you can see, that I just put the add-hoc join outside of the subquery. But, the problem is, that subquery is automatically created and I have an access to that part of algo which creates it and I can modify this algo, and I do not have access to the part of algo which builds the whole query, so the only thing I can do is just to fix the subquery somehow. Anyway, I still can't understand why `INNER JOIN` inside a subquery can slow down the whole query hundreds of times.

**EDIT**

A new version of query with different aliases for each table. This has no effect on the performance:

```
SELECT attr_73206_ AS attr_73270_ 
FROM object_73130_ f1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT id_field, attr_73206_ FROM (
    SELECT m.id_field, t0.attr_73102_ AS attr_73206_ FROM object_73200_ a
    INNER JOIN master_slave m ON (m.id_object = 73130 OR m.id_object = 73290)  AND (m.id_master = 73200 OR m.id_master = 73354) AND m.id_slave_field = a.id 
    INNER JOIN object_73101_ t0 ON t0.id = a.attr_73206_ 
    ORDER BY a.id_order 
) AS b GROUP BY b.id_field 
) AS c ON f1.id = c.id_field
```

**EDIT**

This is the result of `EXPLAIN` command:

```
| id | select_type  |  TABLE  |  TYPE  | possible_keys         |     KEY     | key_len  |   ROWS  |  Extra                          |
| 1  |  PRIMARY     |   f1    |  INDEX |  NULL                 |    PRIMARY  |   4      |  1570   | USING INDEX
| 1  |  PRIMARY     | derived2|  ALL   |  NULL                 |    NULL     |  NULL    |  1564   |
| 2  |  DERIVED     | derived3|  ALL   |  NULL                 |    NULL     |  NULL    |  1575   | USING TEMPORARY; USING filesort
| 3  |  DERIVED     | m       | RANGE  | id_object,id_master,..|   id_object |   4      |  1356   | USING WHERE; USING TEMPORARY; USING filesort 
| 3  |  DERIVED     | a       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,attr_73206_   |   PRIMARY   |   4      |    1    |
| 3  |  DERIVED     | t0      | eq_ref | PRIMARY               |   PRIMARY   |   4      |    1    |
```

What is wrong with that?

**EDIT**

Here is the result of `EXPLAIN` command for the "super-fast" query

```
| id | select_type  |  TABLE  | TYPE  | possible_keys        |     KEY     | key_len  |   ROWS  |  Extra                          
| 1  |  PRIMARY     |   f1    | INDEX | NULL                 |    PRIMARY  |   4      |  1570   | USING INDEX
| 1  |  PRIMARY     | derived2| ALL   | NULL                 |    NULL     |  NULL    |  1570   |
| 1  |  PRIMARY     | t0      | eq_ref| PRIMARY              |    PRIMARY  |   4      |  1      | 
| 2  |  DERIVED     | derived3| ALL    | NULL                |   NULL      |   NULL   |  1581   | USING TEMPORARY; USING filesort 
| 3  |  DERIVED     | m       | RANGE  | id_object,id_master,|   id_bject  |   4      |  1356   | USING WHERE; USING TEMPORARY; USING filesort
| 3  |  DERIVED     | a       | eq_ref | PRIMARY             |   PRIMARY   |   4      |    1    |
```

**CLOSED**

I will use my own "super-fast" query, which I presented above. I think it is impossible to optimize it anymore.

Comment: . . Your use of the `order by` in the subquery before the join is highly suspicious.  MySQL explicitly does not guarantee which values will be returned when you use a field not mentioned in the `group by` clause (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: Did you use [**EXPLAIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) feature?

Comment: If I remove ORDER BY a.id_order, it still has no effect. As I said, the whole problem is in the INNER JOIN object_73101_ etc. Event though it does not slow the subquery itself, it terribly slow down the whole query

Comment: Could you also post `EXPLAIN` results for your super-fast version from the first edit? It seems that `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` can provide additional information.

Comment: It's unclear which part of the query you can modify ? The query consist of an outer query and two nested subqueries (in the second cersion nested subqueries have aliases: C and B), could you explain which subquery can modified, C, or B, or both C and B ?

Comment: can you give us a SQL fiddle?

Comment: according to SQL theory when GROUP BY clause is applied all the selected fields not listed in the GROUP BY must be aggreggates (e.g. MIN, MAX, COUNT).  Try SELECT id_field, MIN(attr_73206_) as attr_73206_ FROM (...

Comment: @alexm: MySQL does not impose that requirement; when you select a non-aggregate field in the `GROUP BY`, it just chooses arbitrarily from the set of values that that field takes for a given group. (See [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html).)

Comment: I can modify the whole join statement. But now I think it does not really matter. I will try to use the super-fast query instead.

Comment: Show us the table definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact nature of the data/query, there are a couple things that I'm seeing:

1. MySQL is notoriously bad at handling sub-selects, as it requires the creation of derived tables.  In fact, some versions of MySQL also ignore indexes when using sub-selects.  Typically, it's better to use JOINs instead of sub-selects, but if you need to use sub-selects, it's best to make that sub-select as lean as possible.
2. Unless you have a very specific reason for putting the ORDER BY in the sub-select, it may be a good idea to move it to the "main" query portion because the result set may be smaller (allowing for quicker sorting).

So all that being said, I tried to re-write your query using JOIN logic, but I was wondering What table the final value (attr_73102_) is coming from?  Is it the result of the sub-select, or is it coming from table object_73130_?  If it's coming from the sub-select, then I don't see why you're bothering with the original LEFT JOIN, as you will only be returning the list of values from the sub-select, and NULL for any non-matching rows from object_73130_.

Regardless, not knowing this answer, I think the query below MAY be syntactically equivalent:

```
SELECT t0.attr_73102_ AS attr_73270_ 
FROM object_73130_ f1 
LEFT JOIN (object_73200_ o
  INNER JOIN master_slave m ON m.id_slave_field = o.id
  INNER JOIN object_73101_ t0 ON t0.id = o.attr_73206_)
ON f1.id = o.id_field
WHERE m.id_object IN (73130,73290) 
AND m.id_master IN (73200,73354) 
GROUP BY o.id_field
ORDER BY o.id_order;
```

Comment: In addition to this (if I'm understanding your original comment correctly), you will want to add the following (covering) indexes if they don't already exist:

On master_slave:  (id_object,id_master,slave_field), On object_73200_:  (attr_73206_,id_field,id_order)

Comment: I'm not even convinced the `ORDER BY` in the subselect will actually enforce the ordering, so it is certainly best to move it outside.

Comment: Agreed.  Well, I believe it will enforce the ordering as long as the original table (object_73130_) doesn't add any new rows (which it's most likely going to do, as it's a LEFT join).  As long as the sub-selected data is passed to the LEFT JOIN in a specific order, I believe the result set will keep it in that order, but I could be totally wrong.  In fact, it wouldn't surprise me if it took the order of the main table's data on disk, and performed the LEFT JOIN after the ORDER BY.  Either way, I completely agree with you that it's very dubious.

Comment: Guys, ordering is absolutelly necessary. Since, as I said, "For each row in the master table the query returns a field from the very first row of its detail table". So, ordering before grouping is the only way to get the desired result. It is a widely used technique. So, the speed of the initial join has practically nothing to do with ordering. Actually, my super-fast query and EXPLAIN command make it easy to understand what was wrong with the first version of the query. As for covering indices, the table master_slave had them too.

Comment: I did not test your query, but I clearly see, that it will not work. Firstly, because the scope of `t0` is the `LEFT JOIN` itself and, secondly, because `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` in combination do not provide the expected behaviour. The last happens because `GROUP BY` may eliminate a row which contains the least `id_order` value.